# How to intercept mysql responses?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

It is possible to intercept `mysql` responses, to inspect the datastream?

My problem is as follows: I have an external tool that I have no control of. It  `select * from mytable where...`. The table has about 100 columns, though the `WHERE` clause only selects on some specific ones.

The external tool then joins the mysql response to a fixed length string to work with.

Now I thought I could maybe collect 90 columns into one column as `CSV` string, and the just return that prepared string by the mysql response.

But therefore I'd have to know how a sql select response exactly looks like.

Source mysql table:

```
id;age;name;col1;...;col100
1;18;john;val1;....val100
2;30;doe;val1;....val100
```

My mysql goal.

```
id;age;name;cols
1;18;john;"val1;...;val100";
2;30;doe;"val1;...;val100";
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: @membersound . . . I don't understand.  Are your source and goal actually *tables*?  Are they strings?  Files?  Do they have separate columns?  They don't look fixed length.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because I have to `LOAD DATA`, and the difference between inserting into 10 columns or into 100 columns is huge! As those columns are never used in selects or updates, I could as well just join the data before batch load.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they are database tables, yes. I did not include the full `CREATE TABLE` statement as it does not matter for my question. All `colN` values are varchars with a maximum length set.

Comment: OK, so if you only need say columns 1, 5, 10, and 90-100, then why not use something like sed or awk to generate the CSV Input file you actually need?

Comment: It's not about the csv. It's about if I could mimik the mysql response. **If** a mysql response is a simple csv string response (which I don't know and therefore want to intercept), then I could prepare the table with just 11 columns (where the later `cols` is a join of `col1...col100`).